chrome browser blocks auto_download with selenium
In python I build a function with an auto-login. After logging in it clicks a download_csv button.
driver = ChromeDriver
Running the code Google Chrome gives "there's something wrong" and gives the name of the download file in a pop-up screen with a cross over the download icon. It seems that Chrome blocks the download.
Any suggestions how to solve this?
